# Cognos converting string to interval minutes error XQE-DAT-0005

Tags: cognos

I'm trying to convert string to interval minutes but when it run it give me below error:
XQE-DAT-0005

```
    Cannot convert the string value '4.027033333333334' to data type interval second.
```

i tried to convert to int the interval but results don't show

Answer (score 1):

Congos can hold only integer value in `INTERVAL` datatype.
As your string contains number that represent fractions of a second I would suggest you converting your string to `real` format and then manipulating with it.
To round a number use one these: `ROUND`, `FLOOR`, `CEILING`:

```
cast (to_integer(floor(to_real([MySring]))), INTERVAL SECOND)
```

You can substitute `to_integer` and `to_real` with `CAST`s - it is less database dependant.
Another way to cast is to use functions of query macros.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to an interval second you should trim string after the precision point since you finally will get an integer value.

so use string helpers to slice your string with a '.' and then use first part to convert to an interval second

something like this

(x.slice(',')[0]).convertToInvervalSecond

Comment: what function to use to get rid of the '.'

Comment: to_integer(to_real(your string))

Comment: I get this error when running the report :
   Data source adapter error: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=TO_REAL;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.63.123